# Hashtag Beside Pins names

Tags: microcontroller, serial, memory, datasheet, firmware

What does Hashtag (#) means when it's added beside some pins names in datasheets..like WE# in the flash memeory pinout or RI# in RS232 FTDI datasheets??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means active-low.

Ideally, active low is indicated by an overbar: \$ \overline{\text{CS}} \$.  But typography doesn't always support overbar (software code, typewriters).  There is half-dozen different typographic conventions to indicate active-low without overbar.   Pound sign [youngsters call it "hashtag"] is one of the most common.

Let's say we have a Chips Select line that's active low.  CS#, /CS, !CS, xCS, nCS, CSn all mean "Chip Select active low".

Comment: Now you made me read about # for several minutes because I only knew it under the name of "number sign" and I was wondering why it would be called pound sign (which is this: £ in my mind). (A hashtag for me was # + some text but not # alone) But now I know it as the [octothorpe](http://blog.dictionary.com/octothorpe/)...